# Break the string on Full Stop for (Chinese, Arabic, Japanese, Russian, Korean, Dutch, Hindi, Greek, Urdu) using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on languge segmentation project. I applied language segmentation for English by using regular expression breaking the string at . ("Full Stop"). Now i want to provide the support for following languages (Chinese, Arabic, Japanese, Russian, Korean, Dutch, Hindi, Greek, Urdu). I want to break the above mentioned language strings on Full stop.

e.g.

For  Chinese Full stop is 。 (Unicode value U+3002)
String

```
以有效應對各種事態」。他還表示，希望以符合21世紀的方式切實深化美日同盟關係。
```

Expected Result

```
Segment 1 :- 以有效應對各種事態」。
Segment 2 :- 他還表示，希望以符合21世紀的方式切實深化美日同盟關係。
```

Same logic I have to apply for other languages (Arabic, Japanese, Russian, Korean, Dutch, Hindi, Greek, Urdu).

Comment: What do you have, and how doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

See [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). You can use `/([。])/` as a regular expression separator. Add the other punctuation characters inside the square brackets. The round parentheses will [capture your delimiters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

In php you might use `preg_split( REGEX , $yourString );`

Replace the word REGEX with your regular expression. Possibly like @janmoesen mentioned.